# Share user between organization

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We have one user who can be part of multiple organizations in our system, we want to create a single user in the system and provide access to various organizations via roles.
i.e user@abc.com is a person and it can be associated with multiple organizations with different roles Like, in Org1 he is an OrgAdmin, in Org2 he is an Employee and in org3 he is a Member.

How we can implement this type of complex system? we have some solutions to build our custom auth module but we want to use OAuth2.0 and OpenIdConnect for other requirements and we are searching for some open source solutions which can fit our requirements.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information provided, My suggestion would be you use URNs and properly assign scopes.

Scopes are requested by the client and MAY (or may NOT) be grated by the Authorization Server.

- example.com:Org1:OrgAdmin
- example.com:Org2:emplpoyee

Scopes might be auto-assigned by the Authorization Server as when it is determined they are an employee or a paid subscriber.

-jim

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is we can export all the scope in a single token. Let's assume we have a client application example.com and the user tries to login into the client then the client will redirect to auth app. auth.example.com. 
Now, Auth server will only provide IdToken or maybe org association for that user, After that somehow client asks for an access token with org isolation so that the access token contains a scope specific to org.

Comment: Again, not much information on you environment but it appears you may want to look into OpenID Connect Federation.
Generally, from what you have described, there would be a auth.example.com and a auth.org2.com Authorization server and it would be up to the "Client" to perform any correlation of these separate Digital Identities.
OAuth and OIDC are based on the end-user control their ability to provide delegated consent to the Client.

Comment: Let me describe it in different words. 
User1 Is part of Org1 and Org2 and both org used a common system. 
Now, user1 access the application at that system ask him for a login, And User1 provide his login details, After that org selection screen will appear, and based on the selected org we are preparing a token. still, we are using our own user management flow we have full control of a system, Now we want to use OpenID Connect to full fill our requirement.

Comment: Is user1 a digital identity that you control? (like an employee)
What is org1 and org2? (An OU or container in LDAP/AD)
What is a common system?
Real-life systems and solutions are always complex and often not suitable for Q&A.